# Possible to run a test against a file when pushed to git and reject in case the push?

Tags: git, automated-tests

Is it possible to:

- Run regex against a file and reject the push by throwing an error when we have a match
- Run some extra tests regarding file size, encoding
- For specific files/folders/branches only

Comment: What in particular are you attempting to accomplish?  What kind of files are you pushing into the repository that you would want to run a regex against, and ensure against a certain size?

Comment: Mainly text files or latex files or bibtex files. We would like to avoid to have wrong syntaxes or illegal chars to be pushed to the repo. The size thing is not really importent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is a remote hook:

`update` is the one you need. You just have to write a script that's running your test against the repository (or the diff) and return a non-zero code if something sounds wrong for you.

More informations here : http://git-scm.com/book/be/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks (on the bottom of the page)